# Пересчитывать значение переменной каждый раз при изменении размеров окна?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть скрипт, который при загрузке страницы вычисляет высоту элемента `infoproduct` и делает высоту `productbaner` равной этому значению. Я хочу, чтобы при изменении размеров окна высота `infoproduct` пересчитывалась, но каждый раз, когда размер окна меняется, значение становится все больше и больше. Подскажите, в чем моя ошибка?

```js
window.onresize = func;
window.onload = func;
function func() {
    const infoproductHeight = document.getElementById('infoproduct').scrollHeight;
    console.log(infoproductHeight);
    const productbaner = document.getElementById('productbaner');
    productbaner.style.height = infoproductHeight+'px';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #f06d06;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.productbaner {
    padding: 3% 5% 5% 5%;
    min-height: 250px;
    position: relative;
     min-height: 300px;
}

.infoproduct {
  padding: 3% 5% 5rem 5%;
}

#infoproduct {
    background: rgba(20,150,240,.7);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 4.5rem 3%;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="productbaner" id="productbaner">
<div class="infoproduct "id="infoproduct">
 Здесь какой-то контент здесь какой-то контент здесь какой-то контент здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  здесь какой-то контент  
</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: нужен воспроизводимый пример

Comment: Ваша ошибка в том что вы не добавили код HTML

Comment: Набросал пример в кодпене https://codepen.io/kadochnikov_k/pen/GROzBEp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не ошибка, у вас в вёрстке `infoproduct` находится внутри `productbaner`-а и когда вы устанавливаете высоту `infoproduct`-а то меняется высота не только `productbaner`-а но и самого `infoproduct`-а, потому что он находится в нём. Если вы напишите раздельно вот так:

```html
<div class="productbaner" id="productbaner"> </div>
<div class="infoproduct "id="infoproduct"> SOME TEXT </div>
```

то у вас получится корректная обработка высоты и пропадёт бесконенчное увелечение высоты

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @КонстантинКадочников Если не трудно, отметье мой ответ как правильный, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае необходимо было, чтобы структура была именно такой, как в примере, решил проблему исправлением скрипта (при изменении размера окна сначала устанавливаю высоту родительского элемента равной 100% и потом выполняю все остальное):

```
window.onresize = func;
window.onload = func;
function func() {
    const productbaner = document.getElementById('productbaner');
    productbaner.style.height = '100%';
    const infoproductHeight = document.getElementById('infoproduct').scrollHeight;
    console.log(infoproductHeight);
    productbaner.style.height = infoproductHeight+'px';
}
```